# Marketing Cloud App SOAP API "Error: API Permission Failed." on every call

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, soap, marketingcloudapi

Overview: I am using SSO to login to my marketing cloud app, and trying to then hit the API to load a list of DataExtensions. However it seems no matter the call I make, I get the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:67502e2e-f4d0-4dd6-8826-83d7a983dda8</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:d52c711b-4baa-4aa9-b06f-085857bd4822</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-dd0b2725-9054-4465-ac7c-eaaea3d6cf54">
                <wsu:Created>2022-03-27T08:34:03Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-03-27T08:39:03Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>Error: API Permission Failed.</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>444a0a04-5390-4425-a7c4-1160aa4d3e0c</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am fairly sure my access token and Auth process is correct, as I can hit the REST API for user info, and if I do not have a valid token/remove it I get an error along the lines of 'Login Failed', so I do not think that is the problem.

So I then thought it may be my permissions. So I set the Api Integration Scope to allow EVERYTHING, including offline access, just to be sure that is not the issue, and still same thing. I even created a new role with access to everything incase it was something to do with my individual user permissions.

[image: Screenshot of Scope]

I am not sure what my next step is now, so any guidance will be appreciated. BTW, here is an example call (without tokens of course).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could be you're using the wrong tenant -- `{{et_subdomain}}` in your case.  You can view the actual request in in the `</>` icon area on the right in Postman.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I do not think so, it is the same tenant I am using for the auth request originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has to be something with the Installed Package -- client id/secret, tenant URL, or business unit scope in the Access tab.

Here's one I just successfully executed:

```xml
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: TENANTHERE.soap.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: text/plain

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://TENANTHERE.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">AUTHTOKENHERE</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>IsSendable</Properties>
                <Properties>SendableSubscriberField.Name</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e0b87e38-69e8-418f-a986-5014c72314db</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9b5e66fd-56b0-41cc-b1b7-fdeff529439d</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-fe3815fc-7298-48fb-9078-8d3e041a0eb7">
                <wsu:Created>2022-03-28T02:56:21Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-03-28T03:01:21Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>99c097be-7f9d-4eec-aa8f-636b966ab4d1</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID>b786014d-45c2-eQ11-8a02-1402ec67ad30</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>TestSendRecipient</CustomerKey>
                <Name>TestSendRecipient</Name>
                <IsSendable>true</IsSendable>
                <SendableSubscriberField>
                    <Name>_SubscriberKey</Name>
                </SendableSubscriberField>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are correct, the issue was with my initial authorization, which worked, but had the wrong scope. I thought leaving empty sets default to whatever is configured for the API Integration, however it was converted to an empty string, which basically means I had no scope.